# Prime Faces Mega Menu Issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to model a menu using the Prime Faces mega menu component but the requirements I have state that there only need to be 2 levels of navigation not three - to elaborate I have included some sample code below.

```
 <p:megaMenu>
<p:submenu label="Data Entry">
      <p:column>
          <p:submenu label="Shoes">
               <p:menuitem value="Size UK 3-5" url="#" />
               <p:menuitem value="Size UK 6-8" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:column>
</p:submenu>
  </p:megaMenu>
```

I would rather do away with the p:submenu label="Shoes" and just have the menu items underneath it - is there anyway to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes to my mind is to hide it using CSS:

```
<p:submenu label="Shoes" style="display: none;">
```